# CullingGroup.onStateChanged does not get called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm experimenting with the CullingGroup Api, however i'm unable to achieve any success because it looks like that my onStateChanged callback will not get called.

I have 24 spheres and a cube which has the following script attached to.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CullingGroupBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    CullingGroup localCullingGroup;

    public Transform[] Spheres;
    public BoundingSphere[] cullingPoints;

    void Awake()
    {
        localCullingGroup = new CullingGroup();

        GameObject[] spheres = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spheres");
        cullingPoints = new BoundingSphere[spheres.Length];
        Spheres = new Transform[spheres.Length];

        for (var i = 0; i < spheres.Length; i++)
        {
            Spheres[i] = spheres[i].transform;
            cullingPoints[i].position = Spheres[i].position;
            cullingPoints[i].radius = 4.0f;
        }

        localCullingGroup.onStateChanged = (CullingGroupEvent evt) => Debug.Log("Changed");
        localCullingGroup.SetBoundingSpheres(cullingPoints);
        localCullingGroup.SetBoundingSphereCount(cullingPoints.Length);
        localCullingGroup.SetBoundingDistances(new float[] { 10.0f, 50.0f });
        localCullingGroup.SetDistanceReferencePoint(transform.position);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        localCullingGroup.SetDistanceReferencePoint(transform.position);
        for (var i = 0; i < Spheres.Length; i++)
        {
            cullingPoints[i].position = Spheres[i].position;
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        localCullingGroup.Dispose();
        localCullingGroup = null;
    }
}
```

The expected behaviour is that when i'm moving the cube the distances should change and the lambda expression should be called yet nothing happens.
Any ideas are appreciated!

**Update:**

The strange thing is that visibility events are sent correctly when using a camera but distance events does not trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you must set a camera in order to calculate distances, which is strange because the DOC says

> If targetCamera is assigned then the bounding spheres will only be
>   culled from the perspective of that camera.

and

> To have the CullingGroup perform visibility calculations, specify the
>   camera it should use

Yet nothing happens when you dont set the camera.

***Additional Note:***

The onStateChnaged event will only trigger when a BoundingDistance was passed eg: from 1 you enter into 2 (The example only contains one)

**Working Solution:**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CullingGroupBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

    private CullingGroup cullingGroup;
    private BoundingSphere[] bounds;

    Transform[] targets;
    public Transform ReferencePoint;

    void Start()
    {
        // All the objects that have a sphere tag
        var gobjs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sphere");
        targets = new Transform[gobjs.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < gobjs.Length; i++)
        {
            targets[i] = gobjs[i].transform;
        }

        cullingGroup = new CullingGroup();

        cullingGroup.targetCamera = Camera.main;
        // Will automatically track the transform
        cullingGroup.SetDistanceReferencePoint(transform);
        // The distance points when the event will trigger
        cullingGroup.SetBoundingDistances(new float[] { 25.0f });
        // Creating Boundingspheres
        bounds = new BoundingSphere[targets.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < bounds.Length; i++)
        {
            bounds[i].radius = 1.5f;
        }
        // Assigning the Bounding spheres
        cullingGroup.SetBoundingSpheres(bounds);
        // if not set it will use all of the array elements(so below code is redundant)
        cullingGroup.SetBoundingSphereCount(targets.Length);
        // Assigning an event when the distance changes
        cullingGroup.onStateChanged = OnChange;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < bounds.Length; i++)
        {
            bounds[i].position = targets[i].position;
        }
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        cullingGroup.Dispose();
        cullingGroup = null;
    }

    void OnChange(CullingGroupEvent ev)
    {
        if (ev.currentDistance > 0)
        {
            targets[ev.index].gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
        else
        {
            targets[ev.index].gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
        }
    }
}
```